# Oracle db query - data format issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm wondering if there is a way to query the oracle db against formatted field value.
Example:

I have a table of postcodes stored in the format of "part1 part2". I want to be able to find a postcode either by searching it using the above format or "part1part2" format. 
What I was thinking is to format the entered postcode by removing the spaces and then query the database like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM POSTCODES_TBL t 
WHERE t.postcode.**Format(remove spaces)** = 'part1part2'
```

The **Format(remove spaces** would convert the postcode from "part1 part2" to "part1part".

My question is, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `regexp_replace`

```
SELECT * 
FROM POSTCODES_TBL t 
WHERE regexp_replace(t.postcode,'\s', '') = 'part1part2'
```

This will remove any whitespace (space, tab, newlines etc)

or if you only want to get rid of spaces, `replace` will work just as well:

```
SELECT * 
FROM POSTCODES_TBL t 
WHERE replace(t.postcode,' ', '') = 'part1part2'
```

More details in the manual:

- [replace](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions153.htm#i78608)
- [regexp_replace](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions149.htm#i1305521)

Answer (score 1):

You could use like

SELECT * 
FROM POSTCODES_TBL t 
WHERE t.postcode like 'part1%part2'